# Requested column in nuget's outdated command is always blank

Tags: nuget, nuget-package

When checking for outdated nuget dependencies I get something like this:

```
$ dotnet list package --outdated
Project `MyProject` has the following updates to its packages
   [net7.0]: 
   Top-level Package                                Requested   Resolved   Latest
   > Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions                  7.0.0      7.0.1 
   > Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk                                     17.7.0     17.7.1
```

For me, "Requested" is always blank - I've never seen all three columns populated in any of my projects. Yet the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-list-package#description) show examples where it is populated.

Why is that?

(I'm using `Directory.Packages.props` and `Directory.Build.props` files, in case that matters.)

Comment: known bug, specific to when using CPM: https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/12765